Using Windows, how can I install Debian upon my SD Card for my Olimex Lime 2 board?
My GNU/Linux machine is currently broken, and I'm borrowing an old Windows machine. I'm trying to install Debian for my Olimex Lime 2.
Debian provides the following command to install the OS for the Lime 2 (and all Allwinner devices):
zcat firmware.<board_name>.img.gz partition.img.gz > /dev/SDCARD_DEVICE

Since zcat is part of the GNU system, I assume it is not actively installed on Windows. Additionally, the /dev/<device> path would need to be adapted to Windows standards.
How can I use this Windows system to create an installation image of Debian for the Olimex Lime 2?

you'll probably need 7zip on the windows computer (to handle .gz file), and some sort of imager for the SDcard (balenaEtcher, win32DiskImager)

@JaromandaX The Olimex Lime 2 uses two images (firmware and "partition.img.gz").
Does BalenaEtcher or win32DiskImager support that functionality? Thank you so much for any help.

you'd decompress both files (7zip), concatenate them (your OS should be able to handle that, something like COPY /B firmware.<board_name>.img + partition.img full.img ), then use the flasher to flash full.img
